# RIP Patricia McKillip

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[She died May 6 at the age of 74](https://www.oregonlive.com/books/2022/05/oregon-fantasy-author-patricia-mckillip-dies-at-74.html), after a long career of fantasy novels, being nominated for both the Hugo and the Nebula, and has her own tag:  [patricia-mckillip](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patricia-mckillip)

Comment: Oh, boo. :(  Every time I checked lists of upcoming books I'd look to see if she had anything coming out.  Every time.  She's one of 4 authors _all_ of whose books are out on my shelves (as opposed to some/most being in storage).

Comment: She was only nominated to Hugo and Nebula :(